# pandas wide_to_long with float in columns name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I can use the example for the wide_to_long and it works fine.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A1970" : {0 : "a", 1 : "b", 2 : "c"}, 
                   "A1980" : {0 : "d", 1 : "e", 2 : "f"},
                   "B1970" : {0 : 2.5, 1 : 1.2, 2 : .7},
                   "B1980" : {0 : 3.2, 1 : 1.3, 2 : .1},
                   "X"     : dict(zip(range(3), np.random.randn(3)))})
df["id"] = df.index

df
   A1970 A1980  B1970  B1980         X  id
 0     a     d    2.5    3.2 -1.085631   0
 1     b     e    1.2    1.3  0.997345   1
 2     c     f    0.7    0.1  0.282978   2

pd.wide_to_long(df, ["A", "B"], i="id", j="year")

   id year
 0  1970 -1.085631  a  2.5
 1  1970  0.997345  b  1.2
 2  1970  0.282978  c  0.7
 0  1980 -1.085631  d  3.2
 1  1980  0.997345  e  1.3
 2  1980  0.282978  f  0.1
```

Now, we the modification in the columns name with float number like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A19.70" : {0 : "a", 1 : "b", 2 : "c"}, 
                   "A19.80" : {0 : "d", 1 : "e", 2 : "f"},
                   "B19.70" : {0 : 2.5, 1 : 1.2, 2 : .7},
                   "B19.80" : {0 : 3.2, 1 : 1.3, 2 : .1},
                   "X"     : dict(zip(range(3), np.random.randn(3)))})
df["id"] = df.index

df
   A19.70 A19.80  B19.70  B19.80         X  id
 0     a     d    2.5    3.2 -1.085631   0
 1     b     e    1.2    1.3  0.997345   1
 2     c     f    0.7    0.1  0.282978   2
```

I have an Empty DataFrame with both the code below:

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, ["A", "B"], i="id", j="year")
```

or

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, ["A", "B"], i="id", j="year", suffix='\w')
```

Any ideas to retrieve this result:

```
       id year
 0  19.70 -1.085631  a  2.5
 1  19.70  0.997345  b  1.2
 2  19.70  0.282978  c  0.7
 0  19.80 -1.085631  d  3.2
 1  19.80  0.997345  e  1.3
 2  19.80  0.282978  f  0.1
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default capturing group for suffixes is `'\d+'`, which does what it's supposed to, but the documentation is misleading/incorrectly worded:

> '\d+’ captures numeric suffixes.

`'(\d+)'` is not the correct capturing group for decimal numbers, and would only capture integer suffixes.

So you need to specify the suffix capturing group manually. Either specify that you want to grab **anything** as the suffix, with nothing as the separator. Or perhaps be safer with something like `suffix='[0-9]+\.?([0-9]+)?'` in the case of numbers with possibly a single decimal eg. (19, 19., 19.1231):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.wide_to_long(df, ["A", "B"], i="id", j="year", sep='', suffix='.*')

                X  A    B
id year                  
0  19.7 -1.182495  a  2.5
1  19.7  1.126017  b  1.2
2  19.7  0.871408  c  0.7
0  19.8 -1.182495  d  3.2
1  19.8  1.126017  e  1.3
2  19.8  0.871408  f  0.1
```